# Boost output impedance simulation

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, simulation, boost

Does anyone know how to measure the output impedance with SIMPLIS?

below is my circuit,

[image]

But the result at low frequency is wrong, it should be flat, anyone knows what happened in my simulation?

[image]

Comment: Is diode D2 always conducting and can be assumed to be a short circuit?

Comment: Hi @Andyaka,

D2 doesn't always conduct

Comment: That makes it difficult to calculate the impedance especially as it is highly influenced by the resonance of L1 and C1. BTW it looks like the right graph to me (when D2 is conducting). I mean 0 dB = 1 ohm, -10 dB = 0.316 ohm, -20 dB = 0.1 ohm etc..

Comment: You have no control loop around this, so I concur with @Andyaka, the graph is probably correct.  A control loop would modify the output impedance, but you're open-loop.  You could try state-space averaging or the PWM switch model to try to calculate what the graph should be at a given duty cycle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the way I performed the \$Z_{out}\$ ac sweep for the analysis in my last [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1949267512) on transfer functions. Please note how the circuit is drawn, with clear connections and well-arranged components. It is then simpler to check the circuit integrity when the layout is clear:

[image]

Then, you need to check the operating point is correct as you would do with SPICE: is \$V_{out}\$ within the expected level with the proper operating mode like CCM in this case? Then, you can have a look at the open-loop output impedance:

[image]

More [SIMPLIS templates](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf) can be freely downloaded from my [webpage](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Spice.htm) and used to perform various analyses like the closed-loop operation of this boost converter. Please note the macro in the right side which automates the compensation elements calculation:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Verbal, 

Thanks, I will follow your method and do it again.

Comment: No reason why it shouldn't work with you : )

Comment: Hi Verbal, 

Do you know how to measure the Zin bode plot?